# Use numbers from file to generate sed commands

Tags: linux, sed

I have in an input file like as follows:

```
1
30
35
90 ...
```

What I would like to do is modify it so that it shows me the following:

```
sed -i '1s///g' file_to_modify
sed -i '30s///g' file_to_modify
```

Do you know how I could do it in Linux?

Comment: this is really confusingly worded... and formatted... can you explain exactly what you did, what you have, and what you want please.

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Add expected output please

Comment: Yes, what you are asking for is possible, even easy. But in order to tell you how, please [edit] your question and i) add an example input file (`file_to_modify`), ii) add the output you want from that file and iii) if you already have a specific sed command, add that sed command.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: with `s///g`, the empty regexp means "use the previous regexp", but here there's no previous regexp, so that code doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a file of line numbers, `lines.list`, and you want to create a `sed` editing script that executes `s///g` on each of the listed lines:

```bash
sed 's:$:s///g:' lines.list
```

Given a file with the four numbers shown in the question, this would generate the `sed` script

```
1s///g
30s///g
35s///g
90s///g
```

It does this by adding `s///g` to the end of each line.  To avoid escaping the slashes, the `s` command in the script uses `:` as an alternative delimiter.

Running this script would be a matter of using `sed -f`:

```bash
sed 's:$:s///g:' lines.list | sed -i -f /dev/stdin file_to_modify
```

This would create the `sed` script as shown before and then apply it to some file called `file_to_modify`. Since I'm using `-i`, this would also make the edits in-place in the file, assuming we're using a `sed` that knows this option (like GNU `sed`).

Note that the editing script would make little sense in itself, though.  An empty regular expression with the substitution command would re-use the most recently matched regular expression. Since there is no such expression in the script, the first `s` command would trigger an error from `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

### What I would do

```
sed -E "s:[0-9]+:sed -i '&s///g' file_to_modify:" file
```

### Output

```
sed -i '1s///g' file_to_modify
sed -i '30s///g' file_to_modify
sed -i '35s///g' file_to_modify
sed -i '90s///g' file_to_modif
```

### Or combined as a single call

```
sed -E 's:[0-9]+:&s///g:' file |
    paste -sd ';' |
    sed "s:.*:sed -i '&' file_to_modify:"
```

```
sed -i '1s///g;30s///g;35s///g;90s///g' file_to_modify
```

Comment: this was the thing I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @Kekevalde22 if this answer helped you most please accept it with the tick mark. And maybe even upvote it too. That's how you can say "thanks" here on the stack exchange sites